# Ruby: Remove middle node from Linked List

Tags: algorithm, ruby, linked-list

Currently, I'm going over the CTCI, I'm working on the problem removing the middle node. I'm using Ruby to go over these problems. I have the following solution.

```
 def remove_middle_node
    node = @head
    count = 1

    while(node = node.next )
      count += 1
    end
    # reset node to point to head
    node = @head
    middle = (count / 2)
    count = 1

    while(node = node.next)

      if(count == (middle - 1))
        node.next = node.next.next
        return
      end
      count += 1
    end
  end
```

Instead of having a `previos_node` I subtract one from the middle. In this case when traversing the Linked List, when I get to the `(middle - 1)`, meaning the previous node before the middle node in the linked list. I delete the middle node and set it to next.

I would like to get feedback on this implementation. In my understanding, this is `O(n)` and time complexity is also `O(n)`. Although I warn you, this Big O notation still a bit unclear to me so time and space complexity might be wrong.

Here is the full Linked List class.

https://github.com/theasteve/ds_and_algos/blob/master/linked_list.rb
 here is the test I used.

```
# TEST
list = LinkedList.new

list.append(1)
list.append(2)
list.append(8)
list.append(3)
list.append(7)
list.append(0)
list.append(4)

list.display
puts '-----------------------------------'
list.remove_middle_node
list.display
```

Comment: I don't get what `this` is in `this is O(n) and time complexity is also O(n)`. Then, constant additional space would be in *O(n)* space as well as in *O(1)* space: if you think an upper bound to be tight, mention that or use *Θ*.

Comment: The wording of  *2.3 Delete Middle Node* is notably different: *delete a node in the middle (i.e., any node but the first and last node, not necessarily the exact middle) of a singly linked list, given only access to that node*.

Comment: `I delete the middle node …` I don't see that `… and set it to next` I see setting the predecessor's successor to the middle node's one.

Answer (score 1):

- [document/comment your code. In the code.](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc)
- re-checking `.next` in the second loop is unusually defensive
- do not have a comment repeat what a statement "does" (`reset node to point to head`):
  have it illuminate what is achieved/*what-for/why* something is done (the way it is)
- the ruby way to have a statement executed, say, `middle` times may be

  ```rb
  middle.times do
      node = node.next
  ```

(Eyeballing `remove_middle_node`, it uses *O(1)* additional space and *Θ(n)* time.)

Comment: (One advantage of using a variable iterating the list half as fast would be the possibility to detect cycles and ensure termination.)

Comment: My Ruby was nothing to boast when it was best.